# Unable to mock service with nuxt and jest

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, jestjs, mocking, nuxt.js

I have a component called External.vue which contains a button that has props and also has a Google Analytic event fired every time it is clicked.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      ref="ctaButtonExternalElement"
      type="submit"
      @click="fireEvent"
    >
      <a
        ref="ctaButtonExternalLinkElement"
        :class="ctaColour"
        class="block rounded-md border border-transparent px-4 py-3 font-medium shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:px-6"
        :href="ctaLink"
      >
        {{ ctaTitle }}
      </a>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    ctaTitle: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    ctaLink: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    ctaColour: {
      required: false,
      type: String,
      default: 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:ring-blue-500',
    },
    event: {
      required: false,
      type: Object,
      default: function() {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },

  methods: {
    fireEvent() {
      if (this.event != null) {
        return this.$ga.event({
          eventCategory: this.event.event_category,
          eventAction: this.event.event_action,
          eventLabel: this.event.event_label,
          eventValue: this.event.event_value,
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see `this.$ga` is injected here by nuxt automatically and in our test we are wanting to load the component so we want to inject the $ga or rather have a mocked version of it.

```js
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import External from './External';
import ga from '@nuxtjs/google-analytics';
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';

describe('Test External Button', () => {
  test('should mock google analytics', async () => {
    const $ga = {ga: {
      event: jest.fn(),
    }};

    const wrapper = mount(External, {
      propsData: props,
      mocks: {
        $ga,
      },
    });

    const button = wrapper.getComponent({ref: 'ctaButtonExternalElement'});
    button.trigger('click');

    expect($ga).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

when I run this test I get this error:

```
 Test External Button › should mock google analytics

    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"ga": {"event": [Function mockConstructor]}}

Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$ga.event is not a function"
```

Is there anyway of mocking $ga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mock looks incorrect. `$ga` has no `ga` property, so that should be removed from the mock.

```js
//const $ga = {ga: {
//  event: jest.fn(),
//}};

const $ga = {
  event: jest.fn(),
};
```

And you'd verify `$ga.event` is called, not `$ga`. Also the `click`-event trigger should be awaited, as the `click`-handler isn't called until the next tick:

```js
//button.trigger('click');
//expect($ga).toHaveBeenCalled();

await button.trigger('click');
expect($ga.event).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: It worked! no errors at all. thank you tony

Comment: @oliviaatkinson Glad to have helped! Please remember to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), since it solve the problem. :)